# Something wrongs with JSP getParameter and JQuery GET ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, web

I need to add GET parameters using jquery ajax when I click on button. For example there is a code

```
<button id="20" class="click">Click me</button>
<button id="21" class="click">Click me</button>
<button id="22" class="click">Click me</button>
```

By clicking on specific button I need to pass the button id

```
myapp.com/mainpage.jsp?check=20
```

But, it should be work using JQuery ajax API. I mean, the param should not be visible in URL, because each time when I will be do changing `check` value, this action will be refresh a page, I needn't it. I wrote a code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".btn-info").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "stuff",
                        type: "GET",
                        data:{ checkId: this.id },
                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log("success: " + response);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr) {
                            console.log("error exception: " + xhr);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

And in the end, I added the JSP code

```
My result: <%= request.getParameter("checkId") %>
```

When I click by specific button, for example by button

```
<button id="20" class="click">Click me</button>
```

In browser logs I saw a html document with value is 20:

[image]

And this correct! But on page this value didn't change and still be null:

[image]

Could you tell me please, why it happens, and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note: forgot to change .btn-info to .click, but problem not in that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the true way for the thing u want.

First you should send the request to a servlet (`doGet` method of servlet). And servlet will return a 'response' value to your jsp. Then in **success** part of ajax function you can change the value of **True result**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-info").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "stuff",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        checkId: this.id
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log("success: " + response);
        $('#trueResult').html(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.log("error exception: " + xhr);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
True result <span id="trueResult"></span>
```